# Pointer exception in JavaFx when trying to recplace scene content

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null, javafx, javafx-2

I just started Java and getting some GUI with Fx but I get an null pointer exception when trying to replace my scenecontent.
In the main the Login.fxml is loaded without any problem but when I click to the button for switching to another fxml I get the error.

The main:

```
    package application;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.ResourceBundle;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
    import javafx.event.EventHandler;
    import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
    import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
    import javafx.fxml.JavaFXBuilderFactory;
    import javafx.scene.Parent;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {

    private Stage stage;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Parent root;
        try {
            root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Login.fxml"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.sizeToScene();
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private void gotoMainView() {
        try {
            MainViewController profile = (MainViewController) replaceSceneContent("MainView.fxml");
            profile.setApp(this);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    void Userlogin()
    {
        gotoMainView();
    }
    private void gotoLogin() {
        try {
            LoginController login = (LoginController) replaceSceneContent("Login.fxml");
            login.setApp(this);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

     private Initializable replaceSceneContent(String fxml) throws Exception {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            InputStream in = Main.class.getResourceAsStream(fxml);
            loader.setBuilderFactory(new JavaFXBuilderFactory());
            loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource(fxml));
            AnchorPane page;
            try {
                page = (AnchorPane) loader.load(in);
            } finally {
                in.close();
            } 
            Scene scene = new Scene(page, 800, 600);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.sizeToScene();
            return (Initializable) loader.getController();
        }



}
```

The Logincontroller class:

```
    package application;

    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.ResourceBundle;
    import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
    import javafx.event.EventHandler;
    import javafx.fxml.FXML;
    import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
    import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
    import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

public class LoginController extends AnchorPane implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    static private Button btntext;
    @FXML
    static private TextField loginusr;
    @FXML
    static private PasswordField loginpwd;

    private Main application;

    public void setApp(Main application){
        this.application = application;
    }


     @Override  
     public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {       
        btntext.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println(loginusr.getText());
                System.out.println(loginpwd.getText());
                application.Userlogin();        
                }
        });     
    }
```

The error occurs at:

```
application.Userlogin();
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The `initialize()` method is called as soon as the FXML is loaded. Have a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/Initializable.html#initialize%28java.net.URL,%20java.util.ResourceBundle%29)

Your `initialize()` is called before `setApp(Main application)`. At this point of time, the `application` object has not been initialized and is `null` !

This means the `initialize()` method is called at

```
MainViewController profile = (MainViewController) replaceSceneContent("MainView.fxml");
```

whereas `application` object which is used inside the `initialize()` is instantiated after this line, when you are using

```
profile.setApp(this);
```

So when you are trying the code `application.Userlogin();` inside `initalize()`, at the time of execution, `application is null` !

Comment: I am really sorry but I don't see what you mean.
Could you please explain?

Comment: I have edited my answer, hope it makes some sense now !

Comment: I understand the problem but what is the best way to solve this? The sample that I got is just with one scene and others that I found on the net were really different from each other

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml